# command line or batch file to pin shortcut to windows 8 start screen (tile)

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1

what command line can I put in a batch file that when ran would create a URL shortcut for a user and place it (pin) to their windows 8 start menu to look like other tiles?

Is there any params to set an icon, color, etc?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a URL file which will be opened by the users default browser with:

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=http://www.google.com`
```

And then save the file with a .url extension. You could do this from a batch program with:

```
echo [InternetShortcut]>google.url
echo URL=http://www.google.com>>google.url
```

Perhaps you can then place this file (google.url) in the start menu by placing it this location: `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`.